What is the best feasible way migrate from Angular 1.5 to Angular 17
We have a new Angular 17, Java 17 , Spring Boot application and an old application which is in Angular 1.5,Java 8 , maven and running in weblogic.
I am planning to migrate( not to re develop) Angular 1.5 project inside Angular 18 application . My thought process is i should be able to copy the whole Java code and angular code with minimal changes or fixes . Is this something feasible to implement or i need to develop
whole Angular 1.5 code into Angular 18. Am very new to Angular development .

AngularJS is way too different to be migrated to angular 18.  It necessitate to rewrite the apps. Some hybrid solution exist but this is not a migration in itself.

Can you please give more insight on hybrid solution

It's doable https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html, but it's not going to be simple. You will have to rewrite a lot of code because AngularJs and Angular 2+ are very different. Google recommends upgrading incrementally https://update.angular.io/, so you'll be walking through the update process 17 times. Really depends on the size of your app and how many libraries you have installed. An alternative is to break up your application into micro front ends, but you'll have to change the architecture of your application if you go with this approach
